# Is there notation to remove trailing zeros with String.Format and percentage?

Tags: c#, string.format

I know it's possible to remove trailing zeros using the `#` in the format pattern:

```
double value = 92;
string formatted = $"{value:0.#}"; // "92"
```

and using `P` gives you a percentage:

```
double value = .9234;
string formatted = $"{value:P1}"; // "92.3%"
```

but is there a way to combined the two to produce percentage with optional decimal?

```
double value .92;
string formatted1 = $"{value:P#}"; // doesn't work. 
string formatted2 = $"{value:P0.#}"; // doesn't work.
```

Anyone know a way to use just formatting to achieve this without having to multiply value by 100? Essentially I want `.92 => 92%` and `.924 => 92.4%`

Comment: if you are concerned about performance, don't worry, multiply is one of those instructions that gets done in a few cycles. CPU can multiply million times before you blink.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, in this case, no it's not about performance, it's about simplicity, but in my actual project, it will improve performance. I'm working on something in UWP and would like to avoid complex bindings and/or custom templates just to remove trailing zeros. It's hard to explain in a few words, but it would actually improve performance if a format pattern can handle it.

Comment: I wish you would ask it in another question considering bindings and UWP. Make sure its not a duplicate though. You can use converter. Pass parameter 100. And inside converter try parse int, multiply value by parameter, convert back to string and return it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter

Comment: I didnt downvote. Why do you think i did? Here is my prove. Upvoted ;) but keep in mind dont oversimplify your question because though your question is answerable, it doesnt answer or address your real problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is a bit embarrassing, but apparently it's this easy:

```
double value1 .92;
double value2 .923;
string formatted1 = $"{value:0.#%}"; // "92%" 
string formatted2 = $"{value:0.#%}"; // "92.3%"
```

The `%` sign is the notation used to multiply the number by 100 and add the percent sign. Using `P` is shorter notation, but `%` let's you customize the output.

So the format string is just like the standard `0.#` but with a percent sign at the end `0.#%`

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-percent-p-format-specifier)  does specify only precision specifier for modification. If you want something like you posted you have to go more tedious way:

```
double value = 0.924;
string formatted = $"{value * 100:0.##}%";
```

Result is: 92.4%

Comment: The OP is specifically asking for a way to do this without multpying by `100`.

Comment: The variable content is not multiplied, only the evalutes expression for the output. If he actually wants solution that is looking really simply for its use case he needs to implement his own format provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: @FilipKonečný, sorry, but this does not answer my question. I already know I can multiple by 100 :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to multiply, you can remove trailing zeros using regex. but if you are after performance, multiply approach (in other answer) is way faster.

```
double value = .9253;
string formatted = $"{value:P2}"; // or P with any number you like.
formatted = Regex.Replace(formatted, @"(?<=\d\.\d+)0+%$|\.0+%", "%");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is overkill. It's easier to multiply by 100 and use the format "0.#"